# Update the view less often

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I developed a program in a QMainWindow, with a QTableView based on a QSqlTableModel. The database uses sqlite.

This program is supposed to display a list of videos. I can normally add some tags and actor to each video (tags and actors are stored in the database). When I have a few videos displayed, everything works fine, but when the number of videos increases, my program raises an exception like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/djipey/informatique/python/bibli/gui.py", line 572, in addTag
liste.addTag(vids_selected, tag_to_add.split(" "))
File "/home/djipey/informatique/python/bibli/liste.py", line 488, in addTag
bdd.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

I'm almost sure the problem doesn't come from liste.py, because I close each connection and cursor. No, my database is busy somewhere else.

I assume the problem comes from the view/model when they display the informations, so I wonder if it's possible to dicrease the display rate? Otherwise, I'm open to every suggestion to fix the problem.

```
def addTag(list_vids, list_tags):

    """ Ajoute tous les tags de list_tags à chaque vid de list_vids. Pour
cela crée un tag dans la table tags, puis établit une relation entre
l'id de la vidéo et l'id du tag créé. Inscrit la correspondance dans
la table videos_tags. """

    bdd = sqlite3.connect("fichiers.sqlite") # ouverture de la base
    bdd.row_factory = sqlite3.Row # accès aux colonnes par leur nom, pas par leur index

    c = bdd.cursor() # obtention d'un curseur

    #On ajoute le tag transmis à la table tags s'il n'existe pas déjà
    for each_tag in list_tags:
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name= ? ", (each_tag,))
        if c.fetchone() is None:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES (?) ", (each_tag,))

            bdd.commit()

    for each_video in list_vids:
        for each_tag in list_tags:
            #On récupère l'id du tag pour s'en servir après
            c.execute("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name= ?", (each_tag,))
            id_tag_recupere = c.fetchone()["id"]

            #On vérifie que le tag à stocker n'est pas déjà associé à la vidéo 
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM videos_tags WHERE id_video = ? AND id_tag = ?", (each_video, id_tag_recupere))
            if c.fetchone() is None:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO videos_tags (id_video, id_tag) VALUES (?, ?)", (each_video, id_tag_recupere))
                bdd.commit()
            else:
                print("Cette vidéo a déjà ce tag")

    c.close()
```

Comment: How are you setting the data in the `QSqlTableModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I had to do the contrary. Thanks to you man :)

In the constructor of my QMainWindow, I initiate the connection to the database, with database.open(). But in my action addTag, this conection was still open, and the matter was another module handles the writing of the tags in the database.

So, to put database.close() at the begining of my action addTag, and database.open() at the end of the action, solved the problem.

Thank you very much, you gave me the answer.